# CSSTransition transition-enter-active event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I'm new to JS, React and CSSTransition so please excuse me if any of this is obvious. I'm trying to enter some basic enter/exit animations for a div (ideally slide in from right and slide out to left, but just trying to use opacity for now to keep it simple).

While I can get the page to render, I can't get and of the following CSS events to work:
*-transition-enter,
*-transition-enter-active,
*-transition-exit,
*-transition-exit-active

However, whilst playing around with it I have managed to get some functionality working using the events:
*-enter-done,
*-exit-done

However, I then can't get it to work for a slide in/out transition.

This has perplexed me, so hoping you can point me in the right direction. A few code snippets:
App.js

```
  switch = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    slide: !prevState.slide
  }));

  render() {
    return (
    <button type="button" onClick={this.switch}> Click </button>

    <CSSTransition
      in={this.state.slide}
      classNames='slide'
    >
       <div>
          <p>Text here</p>
       </div>
    </CSSTransition>
)
```

And the my App.css

```
.slide-transition-enter{
opacity: 0;
}

.slide-transition-enter-active{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.slide-transition-exit{
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-transition-exit-active{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

Comment: The transition should allways be on the element not only when animating

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? What change should I make? Thanks!

Comment: something like that
```.mainclass{
transition: opacity 200ms;

}

.slide-transition-enter{
opacity: 0;
}

.slide-transition-enter-active{
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-transition-exit{
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-transition-exit-active{
  opacity: 0;
  
}```
you can read here for more information
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: I've just tried that but it still doesn't seem to make any difference?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding? I've taken a look at that link but still can't understand the issue. It also doesn't talk the CSSTransition methods which I feel is the issue here.

Comment: Yes but also add a transition on a static class that stays on the element class list always
I called that class mainClass for the example

Comment: Ok, I understand that now, thanks! But unfortunately it's still not working...

Comment: Can you provide a JSbin or other snippet?

Comment: Please provide a working snippet to evaluate how your script works for updating the transition-classes. Therefore it is way easier to find out why the transition CSS doesn't work.

Comment: Well that was tricky enough in itself, getting codepen to work! (after failing with jsbin and jsfiddle!) But here we are, (non) working example: https://codepen.io/Riddleriddleriddler/pen/YzyRmGz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the wrong class names in your CSS here I fixed it
Also you should increse the timeout in your code to make it more smooth

```css
.test{
  transition: opacity 1000ms;
}

/* This fires as soon as the element enters the DOM */
.slide-enter{
opacity: 0;
}

/* This is where we can add the transition*/
.slide-enter-active{
  opacity: 1;

}

/* This fires as soon as the this.state.showList is false */
.slide-exit{
  opacity: 1;
}
/* fires as element leaves the DOM*/
.slide-exit-active{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's sometimes the simplest things! I'm incapable of just reading the boilerplate apparently. Thank you for your help!